# can iOS AudioServicesPlaySystemSound be blocked until sound done playing?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need my software to wait until the sound is completely played before proceeding.
I've got a lot of sounds to develop, so using the callback method will take a lot of development time.

Is there a way to call AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and have it block until it completes playing, without using the callback method?

Comment: In short are you want to wait while sound is finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - you have actually no exact control of when your sound exactly start and finish. Also not that the sound is played in a background thread for the **`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`** API. I have read this [article](http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/playing-audio-in-your-ios-app/) recently for playing sound on iOS take a look at it. You might want to use an other API for playing your sound.